# why variable 'a' is not able to access the new value of document.querySelector('#b1').value

Tags: javascript, dom

```
let a = document.querySelector('#b1').value;
console.log(`a: ${a}`);
document.querySelector('#b1').value = 10;
console.log(`a: ${a}`);
```

Comment: `a` is a copy of the value, it's not linked to the input permanently. You need to assign the variable again.

Comment: `let a = document.querySelector('#b1')` and `console.log(\`a: ${a.value}\`)` will give you the correct ressult

Comment: It will work if you store the element with id b into the variable a, and then fetch it's value whenever required, in that way you will always be able to access the updated value of element with Id b .

Comment: Related: [Array value not updated after changing variable value](/q/43682194/4642212), [Why is the value of my input always empty if I store it in a variable?](/q/58078160/4642212), [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](/q/518000/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments,

When you do `let a = document.querySelector('#b1').value;`  it will parse the value and save it in the variable a.

So doing so, **it won't be updated**. To get the actual value, you'll need to **get it every time**.

Like so :

```js
let wrongWay = document.getElementById("foo").value; // Getting it the wrong way
let rightWay = document.getElementById("foo"); // Getting it the right way
console.log("wrong way value : " + wrongWay);
console.log("right way value : " + rightWay.value);

// Changing input value
document.getElementById("foo").value = "new value";
console.log("Changed value !");

console.log("wrong way value : " + wrongWay); // The value isn't updated as it is saved as a string -> so it didn't get any update
console.log("right way value : " + rightWay.value); // By getting it, you are sure to get the right value
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" value="old value" >
```